# parsing the JSON response throws error

Tags: javascript, json

```
Parse error on line 4:
.../2012",    "Data": "JVBERi0xLjMNCg0KMjA
----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['
```

I get a very huge response which i cannot paste here from my service, i get this error in **jsonlinit**. How to handle such responses in javascript bypassing.

**Added Sample Response**

```
{
    "CreateByFullName": "asas",
    "CreateDateTime": "11\/05\/2012",
    "Data": "JVBERi0xLjMNCg0KMjAxIDAgb2JqDQo8PA0KL0UgMzQ1MDQNCi9IIFsg==",
     "DocumentId":1540,"DocumentIdSpecified":false,"DocumentTypeName":"big sq bmp","FileType":"PDF","LastModifiedDateTime":"07\/14\/2004","LastModifiedFullName":""}
```

Comment: can you paste a sample of the big response? from that line it looks like youre missing a ".

Comment: The actual error probably comes before this, maybe a missing open quote on the date that precedes it?

Comment: @Pointy he's doing that, he wrote jsonlinit however :)

Comment: yes sorry I'm dumb this morning :-)

Comment: Does that long string really end without a closing quote character?

Answer (score 0):

As has been remarked you full sample is valid JSON.

I can provoke the error you see by inserting a newline into the `Data` string. It appears to be base-64 data, are you sure there are no embedded newlines?